# Error while running angular 8 server. How do I resolve Require stack error?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

When I try to run an angular server using `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --open` I receive an error ->

```
[error] Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:83:19)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:41:41)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:71:63)
    at async ServeCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:124:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:201:24)
    at async default_1 (C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:62:31)
```

I tried reinstalling angular but still it was not fixed. I also tried `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular` but it didnot work

Comment: Can you trying giving this first ```npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular``` then give ```npm install``` ..

Comment: Thanks but it did not resolve the issue. optional components got skipped

Comment: Couldn't get you.. Still you are facing the same issue after running the above command??

Comment: yes same issue.

Comment: May I know how you resolved?

Comment: I was not running it in project root directory. I am new to angular. Can you please post it as an answer so that i can mark it as solved.

Comment: I thought you might be running in the right directory only, So only deleted that comment later.. But it is good that fortunately you have seen that comment.. Posted as answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue states that the dependency `@angular-devkit/build-angular` cannot be find to build the project..

You should be able to resolve this error by downloading the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` dependency from your project's root directory.

So run the installation command from the

> `<root_directory_of_angular_app>`